# 500 internal server error ONLY occurring when visiting mobile site via an Instagram bio

Tags: html, apache, ubuntu, instagram

I've had trouble with Instagram's built in browser in the past, but this issue has been by far the worst.

My site works perfectly normal everywhere I have tried, both desktop and mobile, except for when I am using Instagram and try to visit the site via a link in my bio. Does anyone know why this may be causing a 500 internal error? Cannot replicate the issue anywhere else and have not seen any articles on it. Checked the error log and here is the error I received:

'Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.'

I'm running Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu).

Please keep in mind that this ONLY occurs when directly visiting the site via a link on an Instagram page's bio. Big problem though because a lot of our customers visit the site via Instagram. Here is the contents of my .htaccess as I've read the redirect issue may be related to this. I have it set up to redirect non-www to www ('test' is being used here as a placeholder for the actual website's info).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Also, the 500 internal error only occurs when attempting to visit any page *other* than my index.html... home page does not receive any errors. AND, if you go to the home page on Instagram's browser, *then* you can successfully visit all other pages without a 500 internal error by simply navigating to them from the home page. The 500 internal error only occurs when trying to directly visit a page other than index.html

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. But my reason was kind of dumb.
I was researching about tons of bots on my websites.
And I put a little logger. I had (255) for User Agent.
And it was enough for all browsers.
But only built-in Instagram browser has gigantic user agent that was breaking my SQL...